# Rails. Preview document from S3 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, carrierwave, fog

I uploaded pdf documents on s3 using carrierwave and fog. Is there a way for users to preview content without downloading it?

Comment: By preview do you mean read the entire document or to be able to see some cover page?

Comment: It will be CV. 1-2 page max. Would be great to see the entire document. But i'm interested in both solutions because i'm new to rails and i want to absorb as much as i can

Comment: I want users to have access to it without storing it somewhere in the file system. Every user has one CV. CV is on amazon s3. And i want to make CV visible while looking on user's show page. And i can't seem to find any ruby gem for this.

Comment: The solution I've posted below should work. I've seen a few issues posted concerning s3 problem but they seem to have been user issues.

Answer (score 1):

By the end of the day i realised that i might have not only pdf but other types of files. So in **fog.rb** i set public to false so it generates uniqe url's

```
  config.fog_public = false
```

And in my **view.html.erb** i do a simple link_to so it would open document in a new window without saving it like this:

```
<%= link_to "View CV", @applicant.cover.attachment.url, :target => "_blank"  %>
```

Maybe there is way to *preview links* but for the moment that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [PDF-JS](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). There is a Rails [gem](https://github.com/shyammohankanojia/pdfjs_rails) but it hasn't been updated in 2 years. I would probably just download the latest [version](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download).